# how to secure android app and webserver communication

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

My android app uses GCM to send or receive text messages. At first, when a user install my app, it uses the GCM api to get a GCM_id from  Google. After getting this long GCM id, app sends this id to my web server to say that this client is registered with that id.

My question is that about this step. Since firstly app gets the GCM id and sends it to my web server, I think, someone can listen the requests of the app and sends dummy GCM_ids for this client (or any other clients if guess my client id format). How can I secure this step to prevent unwanted interrupts and attacks.

While creating gcm_id, if google would send this id to my server also before sending it to client, it would be a solution to my problem. But google sends it to client only directly.

ps: Using ssl is not a solution I think. Because it can also be opened by programs like fiddler .

Comment: SSL is the solution, fiddler and such can read it if they are present on the device that sends the data, but not in the transit.

Comment: SSL sounds like your only solution.

Comment: but if you trace it with fiddler, you can see apps behaviour and can write another application that manipulate the data and send it to your server right?

Comment: If you have the device that sends the data, you can do whatever you want anyway.

Comment: Your question should be probably moved here: http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: If not SSL, you can encrypt the `GCM_ID` with your own algorithm and decrypt that again on  he server side. You need to make your own algorithm for this.

Comment: If the client performs the encryption how is it more secure? you should use SSL, that's all.

Comment: Do some authentication on your server.  Limit the number of times a user can post to your server.  There are a lot of things you can do

Comment: encryption on client side is not secure as Udi said. someone can decompile the app code and see how you encrypt it. Also there is already an authentication on server but I couldnt find the best solution for apps security.

Comment: If the client is going to use the gcm-id in the future, then it needs to be stored on the device and transit on the network when used, so you should not bother only about registration. If it is only used by your server app, then why does the registration have to happen on the user's device?

Comment: gcm id have to be stored to device, and also on the server to send messages to other participants. Since gcm_id is a key field to the related device, at server I want to match that device and the gcm_id securely if possible